# Split Function in Python

Tags: python, text, split

I have to write a program in Python where it asks the user to enter a string and it only prints out those words beginning in "s" or "S".  I am using the `.split` function to create a list of the words.  However, I am having trouble figuring out how to get Python to recognize those words beginning with either "s" or "S".  Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [`.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) method of a string like so:

```
>>> mystr = 'Super Sally rode a super ship.'
>>> [x for x in mystr.split() if x.lower()[0] == 's']
['Super', 'Sally', 'super', 'ship.']
>>>
```

You could also use the [`.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method instead of indexing the string at position 0:

```
# This method, while longer, is really clear as to what's going on.
[x for x in mystr.split() if x.lower().startswith('s')]
```

Comment: I'd prefer `x.lower().startswith("s")`

Comment: @Claudiu - Lol.  I was just typing that. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `startswith` method of string in combination with the `lower` method which converts a string to all lowercase letters.

```
words = raw_input().split()
for word in words:
    if word.lower().startswith('s'):
        # do something
```

The method `startswith` will return True if and only if the calling string begins with the substring that you pass to it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing @iCodez's fantastic example string - here's a regex approach:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = 'Super Sally rode a super ship.'
>>> re.findall(r's\S+', mystr, flags=re.I)
['Super', 'Sally', 'super', 'ship.']
```

This saves having to split the string up and explicitly normalising case for the comparison.

Also, you can tweak it slightly to not capture unwanted punctuation, eg:

```
>>> re.findall(r's\w+', mystr, flags=re.I)
['Super', 'Sally', 'super', 'ship']
```

Answer (score 0):

use `startswith` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

```
for x in your_string.split():
    if x.upper().startswith('S'):
        print x
```

Answer (score 0):

`startswith` actually takes a tuple.

So:

```
words = raw_input()
print [word for word in words.split() if word.startswith(('s', 'S'))]
```

would sound a lot like english and is easily readable. I'd prefer it over `.lower()`